# pdo can work with mysqli - it is good to use it at the same time

Tags: pdo, mysqli

this is how I want to hear about pdo can work with mysqli?, or should it all be pdo or mysqli?

Can you use the same mysqli and pdo can use the same?

I have looked at this page about pdo

[Mysqli - pdo](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Comment: You should never mix connection drivers for anything, especially not a database. I personally use a database class that I wrote, and I execute queries through that, like: `DB::query("SELECT * FROM table");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- this is how I want to hear about pdo can work with mysqli?

**NO**

- or should it all be pdo or mysqli?

**YES**

- Can you use the same mysqli and pdo can use the same?

Use either mysqli or PDO but do **not** mix them